# Apache (on OS X Lion) isn't reading .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using OS X Lion's built-in Apache server. I placed a `.htaccess` file in my personal Sites directory, but Apache isn't reading it. My username is tophtucker, so the file is in `/Users/tophtucker/Sites/`. But whether I make `.htaccess` valid or gibberish or just `test` or whatever, it has no effect. If `.htaccess` contains just "`test`", I should get an error when I go to `localhost/~tophtucker/`, but I don't.

`.htaccess` works in other directories (like subdirectories of `Sites`). `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in `httpd.conf`, and `AccessFileName` is set to `.htaccess`. It's just something about the `Sites` directory. Does Apache give it weird special treatment or something?

Comment: Check your apache config and make sure `AllowOverride` is set to `All` for all directories and not just one directory.

Comment: Are there any helpful messages in the logs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I figured it out:

When you're using personal sites with Apache, an additional configuration file is created in `apache2/users/tophtucker.conf` (or whatever your username is). `AllowOverride` in *that* configuration file was still set to `None`. I set it to `All`; problem solved!

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk probably need(ed) to restart apache on your machine. apparently `apache restart` but I had to run `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`